# bluez : Can not install bluez-utils

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez

Dose someone try "sudo apt-get install bluez-utils" successfully on raspberry pi ?

and I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bluez-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package bluez-utils has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In future it is important that you give information on which version of the operating system you are running. However, making an educated guess, I think you may be running raspbian Jessie.

In Jessie, the bluez-utils package has been removed. I believe you simply need to run `sudo apt-get install bluez`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Jessie, as the previous answer...

In Jessie, the bluez-utils package has been removed. Bluez 5 either includes it or has all of the functionality of it, I'm not sure which.

Using aptitude (apt-get) as the previous answer will give you a very old version (Bluez 5.23 currently), but is the easiest way. If you want the latest version, please find it on http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth and install the tarball. i.e.:

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.49.tar.xz
tar xvf bluez-5.49.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.49
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

Installing Bluez appears very finicky, and I suggest the more detailed tutorial at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66540/installing-bluez-5-44-onto-raspbian/83835#83835 if you decide to go this route.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Then I tried to download a tar and build it myself however the `./configure` script could not finish.
Turned out I was missing dependencies.
Running

```
sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev
```

fixed it for me. I followed [these instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation) and it worked.

However I downloaded a version 5.52 as it was the newest available at the time.
If you need to wget a tar file and your source doesn't work you can try getting [it here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/).